# "iPad app lookAndFeel" with php website

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website in php which can be used as ipad app. 
When you place a website into the start window of a ipad you receive a sort of "fake" app. 
I used this script to open links in the same window because when you don't use this, safari is going to open a new tab.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.assign($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
</script>
```

This works fine for all my a href's generated in html like `<a href="....">...</a>`. But for my links in php `echo "<a href='....'>" . "'....'" . "</a>"`, it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Javascript works on htmlcode so that should not matter.  Have you checked the source-code of the generated page to see if your links are  valid html?  And in general, if your whole page is valid?

Comment: @Zombaya, i'm really ashamed to say that i was forgot to attach this: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
After updating the file with this code, everything words, i validate the page and their were still a few errors, but i fixed them, i will update my code above, so everybody can see the working code, PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: :-) happens to the best of us.  Congrats on solving it yourself.  It would be clearer if you posted your solution as an answer and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer from original poster moved from his question to an answer here.)

> Problem solved with adding the following code above the script paragraph:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```